# returnURL removing friendlyURL values

Tags: asp.net, friendly-url

When users login from the main page it sends an id as part of the friendly URL

e.g.

```
https://MyDomain.com/Secure/Landing/23
```

Where landing is Landing.aspx and 23 is the ID. This is redirected back to the login page, but now we have

```
https://MyDomain.com/Secure/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fSecure%2fLanding%2f23
```

At the login page

```
Dim vList As IList = Request.GetFriendlyUrlSegments()
```

returns 0 and cannot set the ID.

What is the best way to handle with  friendly urls? Or do I have to resort back to sending it as a query string?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to get the segments from the login page? Why not grab the path from the query string and then redirect to that path upon successful login?

Comment: Hey Mason - The ID part is critical to the login process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this was the only way I could find of getting round the issue

```
 Dim vURL As String = Request.Url.Query
 Dim vSubString As String = vURL.Substring(vURL.Length - 1)
 Dim i As Integer = 1
        Do While IsNumeric(vSubString)
            vSubString = vURL.Substring(vURL.Length - i)
            i += 1
        Loop
 vSubString = vURL.Substring(vURL.Length - (i - 2))
```